# How to remove one item on my data base when I click on my "delete" button?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to android studio, and for my android application I'm use Firebase.
I want to remove one item from my database when I click on my button `delete(btnDelete)`.

```
    String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    Query query= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference().child("users").child(uid).child("foto");



        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            foto_root=itemView.findViewById(R.id.foto_root);
            tvNameF=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNameF);
            tvPhoneF=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPhoneF);
            tvAdressF=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAdressF);
            tvMailF=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvMailF);
            tvNoteF=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNoteF);
            btnDelete=itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
        }

        public void setTvNameF(String tvNameFs){
            tvNameF.setText(tvNameFs);
        }
        public void setTvPhoneF(String tvPhoneFs){
            tvPhoneF.setText(tvPhoneFs);
        }

    }

    /*
    get on dataBase
     */
    private void fetch() {
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Foto> options=
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Foto>().setQuery(query, snapshot -> new Foto(
                snapshot.child("id").getKey(),
                snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString(),
                snapshot.child("phone").getValue().toString(),
                snapshot.child("adress").getValue().toString(),
                snapshot.child("email").getValue().toString(),
                snapshot.child("note").getValue().toString())).build();
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Foto, FotoActivity.ViewHolder>(options) {

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.foto_item,parent,false);
                return new ViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i, @NonNull Foto foto) {
                viewHolder.setTvNameF(foto.getNameF());
                viewHolder.setTvPhoneF(foto.getPhoneF());
                viewHolder.setTvAdressF(foto.getAdressF());
                viewHolder.setTvMailF(foto.getEmailF());
                viewHolder.setTvNoteF(foto.getNoteF());
                viewHolder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                    delete();
                });
            }

        };
        rvFoto.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    private void delete() {


        Toast.makeText(FotoActivity.this, "remove", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void viewRecyclerViewFoto() {
        linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rvFoto.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        rvFoto.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }
}    


// adapter class

String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

private void setInfoFoto() {
        DatabaseReference databaseReference=
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(uid).child("foto").push();
        Map<String,Object> mapFoto=new HashMap<>();
        mapFoto.put("id",databaseReference.getKey());
        mapFoto.put("name",etNameF.getText().toString());
        mapFoto.put("phone",etPhoneF.getText().toString());
        mapFoto.put("adress",etAdressF.getText().toString());
        mapFoto.put("email",etMailF.getText().toString());
        mapFoto.put("note",etNoteF.getText().toString());

        databaseReference.setValue(mapFoto);

    }
```

I want remove one item from `foto` and not all database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the following in your delete function, this will delete the value of "phone" node.  You will need to know the uid of the user you want to delete otherwise you can replace it with a database node reference but then that will delete phone from all the user ids.  Basically you will listen to the foto node, get all the push ids and loop through the push ids to remove the desired node.

Declare The Variables

```
private static final String TAG = "TestActivity";
private DatabaseReference fbDbRef;
```

OnCreate

```
final String uid = "youruid";
fbDbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users")
         .child(uid).child("foto");
```

Your Function

```
private void delete() {

fbDbRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                final String pushKey = snapshot.getKey();
                Log.d(TAG, "pushKey: " + pushKey);
                fbDbRef.child(pushKey).child("phone").removeValue();

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: my problem persists because I can not point to the right file.
I think the problem is due to the fact that I'm using the push () method that generates an id by click.

I would like to point to the id of the foto object in order to be able to remove it

I attach my object to firebase.

Comment: please see my updated answer, I did not realize you were using a push key

Comment: Thank for your help but i m changed my id on name and i dont use push so now my user need to insert name and this name is the id.